# How to implement "Cursor displays at the same depth as objects being targeted" in Unity for Daydream

Tags: google-vr

For Daydream games Google has a requirement where it says:

"Cursor displays at the same depth as objects being targeted"

Description here: https://developers.google.com/vr/distribute/daydream/design-requirements#UX-C4

Now I have tested the Google demos, tried implementing this myself. But I have no idea how to proceed. Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this on Unity using the default scripts given by Google in the demos?

Answer (score 0):

Your interactive objects have been placed too far from the camera. Since the cursor's max distance from the control is about 0.75 meter. It will not be placed on your item. 
Move the object closer to the camera should fix this.